# JS убрать кириллический текст из массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

Подскажите, пожалуйста как очистить массив от кириллических символов? Приведу пример

```js
let dirtyArr = ["пробаhttps://www.google.com/", "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/", "бла", "GoogleКомпания", "123буба"]
let clearedArr /// ["https://www.google.com/","https://ru.stackoverflow.com/", "Google", "123"]
```

Как из dirtyArr получить clearedArr ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let dirtyArr = ["пробаhttps://www.google.com/", "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/", "бла", "GoogleКомпания", "123буба"]
 
 let clearedArr = dirtyArr.map(s => s.replace(/[а-яА-ЯёЁ]+/g,'')).filter(e => e!='');
 console.log(clearedArr);
```

Comment: @Leonid проглядел, спасибо. /[а-яА-ЯёЁ]+/ - почему бы и нет.